# Cannot offer bounty

Tags: support

It's been more than five days since I posted [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52668/small-non-native-firefox-icons), yet I cannot see the option to offer bounty. I think someone also requested the question be closed (there's 1 mentioned in parenthesis besides the close button), does it have something to do with the inability to place bounty?

Answer (score 2):

Today I noticed I can offer a bounty, and promptly did so. Can't figure out the reason.

Comment: it likely hadn't been a full 5 days according to the system.

Comment: @Marco, The question was asked on Jul 11, reported to Meta Jul 16...

Comment: You asked the question July 11th at 13:17Z, the meta question was opened July 16th at 08:12Z You're not technically at 5 days until July 16th 13:18Z

Comment: @Marco, I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi That should be an answer instead... despite being 5 years old. But, please edit it: it's 2 days now, not 5 days. Maybe it was 5 days in the past.